# Can't insert code in message when report MantisBT

Tags: mantis

I was trying to report a bug using MantisBT. In my report message contain the following code:

```
<p><a href="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com')">Google.com</a></p>
```

But it showing as

```
javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com' [^])
```

How can I get the code to display properly in MantisBT?

Comment: Mantis is pretty restrictive on what you're allowed to use, even `<a>` tags are blocked and I'm guessing JavaScript isn't allowed in any way, see : http://inform7.com/mantis/view.php?id=259

Comment: @CD001 So is there anyway that I can get the code displayed on the message of the report?

Comment: If you want to show the source code, just use standard HTML escaping (`&lt;` ... `&gt;`) and wrap it in a `<pre>` tag for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by CD001 above, Mantis limits which tags are allowed in text fields for security reasons.

You can configure which ones are allowed by updating your configuration [[1]](https://mantisbt.org/docs/master/en-US/Admin_Guide/html-desktop/#admin.config.html), e.g. update the following items in your *config_inc.php* file:

```
$g_html_valid_tags = 'p, li, ul, ol, br, pre, i, b, u, em, strong';
$g_html_valid_tags_single_line = 'i, b, u, em, strong';
```